# Looking for references to WordPress Popularity Statistics

Tags: statistics

I found a [recent report](http://hackertarget.com/2011/03/web-tech-2011-report/) putting WordPress at 10-15% of the Alexa Top 1 Million Sites.

Do you have any references to similar data or reports (not only Top 1M)?

Answer (score 1):

### Most of the CMS usage stats originate from [Built With](http://trends.builtwith.com/).

> BuiltWith Internet Technology Usage
> Statistics provides free information
> updated weekly regarding the most
> popular technology used on the web
> across all technology areas including
> analytics, advertising, frameworks and
> website widgets.

#### I've put together a collection of various reports around the web.

### Google Trends

[image]

### WordPress.com (Does not include self hosted)

[image]

## BuiltWith WordPress Usage Trends

[image]

### CMS Distribution Stats

[image]

### CMS Distribution Comparison[image]